# OpenGL Creating a sphere emitter using timer in C#

Tags: c#, opengl, timer

I am currently using openGl and need to emit two different types of sphere from a box. 
I have made the sphere into a structure and implimented two arrays - an orange and blue sphere array.
I also have a timer class.
At the moment, in the OnRenderFrame it draws however many balls there are in the array by looping through, and on the onUpdateFrame it moves all the balls in the array using a loop.

However, they are all being created simultaneously. They need to form one after another.

Here is what I have tried so far, it is in the OnLoad method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) //loop through - set to two for now just for testing purposes


  {
           oldTime = currentTime(); //get time now
          if(oldTime < currentTime())
            {

           orangeArray[i] = new orangeBall(); //create a new ball

            }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

        }
```

And this is the method to get the time:

```
   private float currentTime()
    {
        float currentTime = mTimer.GetElapsedSeconds();
        return currentTime;
    }
```

However, this causes my program to crash and not even load correctly.

Thanks
Lucy

Comment: You are missing braces around your `if` body.

Comment: Sorry, corrected it and still having an issue